# Adding header line to export csv in Python

Tags: python

I want to add a header line my final output csv with Python. How can I do that? First I am removing header of my main file `items.csv` because at the end python adds `'target'` word to the header too. But after adding word I want to write a new header.

Here is my code:

```
import csv
from itertools import islice
import os

with open('items.csv') as sample, open('items_50.csv', "w") as out:
    csv1=csv.reader(sample)
    header = next(csv1, None)
    csv_writer = csv.writer(out)
    sirali = sorted(csv1, key=lambda x:int(x[0]), reverse=True)
    csv_writer.writerows(islice(sirali,50))


file1=open('items_50.csv','rb') 
readfile=csv.reader(file1,)
file2=open('final.csv','wb')
writefile=csv.writer(file2,delimiter='"')
result=()


for row in readfile:   
    result= [row[0]+','+row[1]+','+row[2]+','+row[3]+'target']
    writefile.writerow(result)

file1.close()
file2.close()
```

An example for my final.csv right now:

```
0,apple,orange,gettarget
25,steven,jack,sendtarget
33,pencil,book,sendtarget
8,notebook,cellphone,gettarget
```

I want to make it like this:

```
count,thing,owner,action
0,apple,orange,gettarget
25,steven,jack,sendtarget
33,pencil,book,sendtarget
8,notebook,cellphone,gettarget
```

Thank you.

Comment: use `writerow` like with other data.

Comment: BTW: you can do `row[3] += 'target'` and later `writerow(row)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do befor `for` loop:

```
writefile.writerow(["count", "thing", "owner", "action"])
```

BTW: you can do

```
for row in readfile:
    row[3] += 'target' 
    writefile.writerow(row)
```

Comment: it shows like this: `count"thing"owner"action ` no commas between them and extra quotes !

Comment: because you change `delimiter` and now it uses `"` instead of comma `,` - remove `delimiter='"'`

Comment: When I remove  `delimiter='"'` it puts header that I want but it adds quotes start and end of each lines. like this: `"0,apple,orange,gettarget" `

Comment: Ok done. I used your BTW solution with removing delimeter. Thank you.

Comment: BTW: you could do this even shorter with `pandas` because it can change all values in row without `for` loop and it doesn't change header.

Answer (score 0):

Before loop at this condition

`if os.path.getsize(f_path) > 0:
     writefile.writerow(["count", "thing", "owner", "action"])`

This would add the row if the file is empty.

Comment: I am talking about the file on which you're writing

Comment: I see. I think its same solution with furas but another problem occurs :)

Comment: Don't use `for row in readfile:   
    result= [row[0]+','+row[1]+','+row[2]+','+row[3]+'target']
    writefile.writerow(result)` use append to append variables to list

Comment: Also you can do it like this `result = [ row[0], row[1] ]`